# Android app unfortunately stopped when trying to download a file from an internet server using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I used the following code in my app.

```
 package com.kalusudu.dp.smarthike;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class RecentStories extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recent_stories);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        text1.setText("Knuckles mountain range is a part of the Hill Country of Sri Lanka which is also about 3000 Ft or 915 Mts. from sea level and covers an area of about 90 Sq. Milles or 234 Sq. Km of land extent.");

        TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        text2.setText("Knuckles mountain range is a part of the Hill Country of Sri Lanka which is also about 3000 Ft or 915 Mts. from sea level and covers an area of about 90 Sq. Milles or 234 Sq. Km of land extent.");


        ImageView imageviewOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView01);
        imageviewOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecentStories.this, Cloud.class);
                //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                //intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://m.facebook.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        // execute this when the downloader must be fired
        final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(RecentStories.this);
        downloadTask.execute("https://maps.awesome.com/sd.f");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recent_stories, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}

// usually, subclasses of AsyncTask are declared inside the activity class.
// that way, you can easily modify the UI thread from here
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private Context context;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
            // instead of the file
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            // this will be useful to display download percentage
            // might be -1: server did not report the length
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())+"/stories.data");


            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user
        // presses the power button during download
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                getClass().getName());
        mWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mWakeLock.release();
        if (result != null)
            Toast.makeText(context,"Download error: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(context,"File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The app stops as soon as it starts. What is the reason for this?

When I comment the following line the app runs.

`downloadTask.execute("http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc4871.txt");`

The url is not a valid one. but the result is same with a real one too.

Permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: If you experience a crash, always include the exception in your question

Comment: Did you add android.permission.INTERNET to your manifest file?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I am viewing the logcat in android studio. But I cannot find an exception :(

Comment: Yes @YasharAliabasi

Comment: Can u add full error trace and full manifest permission list please?

Comment: @YasharAliabasi I added permissions. What is meant by error trace ? I am using android studio. Is it logcat ?

Comment: yes log cat, filter it with error you will get error trace put that here

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
downloadTask.execute("http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc4871.txt", "", "");

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //visible progress bar

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
                // instead of the file
                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                            + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                }

                // this will be useful to display download percentage
                // might be -1: server did not report the length
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                input = connection.getInputStream();

                File sourcePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                File path = new File(sourcePath + "/" + "stories.data" + "/");

                path.mkdir();

                File file = new File(path, "/" + "rfc4871.txt");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }
                output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    // allow canceling with back button
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);



        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(final Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
//            Log.e("progressing", "" + values[0]);
//            edt_search.setText("" + values[0]);
//            new Thread(new Runnable() {
//                public void run() {
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
//            tv_downloading.setText("" + values[0] + "%");
//                }
//            }).start();


        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String s) {
            super.onCancelled(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }
 }
```

and also add this pernissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: if your target and compile sdk is higher than lolipop then you have to refer this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html